# pcm_plug.c:67: snd_pcm_plug_close: Assertion `plug->gen.slave == plug->req_slave' failed

Tags: c++, c, alsa, libasound, libalsa

I'm using ALSA for the first time and am seeing the error:

> pcm_plug.c:67: snd_pcm_plug_close: Assertion `plug->gen.slave == plug->req_slave' failed.

This occurs when I attempt to close the PCM:

```
snd_pcm_close(pcm);
```

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that I was inadvertently calling `snd_pcm_close` twice. Removing the second call fixed the failure.